# Add importxml and importhtml tags

Tags: discussion, clean-up, tag-clean-up

We have a *ton* of questions regarding the [ImportXML](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=importxml+-%5Bimportxml%5D+is%3Aq) or [ImportHTML](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=importhtml+-%5Bimporthtml%5D+is%3Aq) functions in Google Sheets. It would be useful if they were easier to find, especially as a lot of them are quite similar and those functions require some specialized expertise to answer.

As such, I've created [importxml](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/importxml) and [importhtml](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/importhtml) tags. It'd be great if we could get those questions appropriately tagged.

Comment: Other members of the "import family" are [tag:importdata] and [tag:importfeed]. Regarding the first, there are several questions but the second appears to be included only on textual documentation cites included on Q&A

Comment: @Rubén: Not much point in having the tag if it doesn't get used. Perhaps the whole lot can be merged into a generic `import-functions` tag.

Comment: @ale: You are right. So far I only found two questions about [tag:importfeed].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that all of the appropriate ImportXML and ImportHTML questions have been appropriately tagged.