# Do we need to extend the [importxml] wiki?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Recently [a clean-up project](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4530/88163) was started related to [importxml](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/importxml) and [importhtml](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/importhtml).

Rightnow the [importxml](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/importxml) wiki includes a quotation of the official help article which only describes the syntax and point users to W3School to learn about xPath. I think that we could improve it.

IMPORTXML requires two arguments, an URL to a file to be examined, I call it "the source file", and a xPath query.

Also I think that most of the questions about IMPORTXML fall in at least one of the following categories:

- The **source file** doesn't follow the XML markup rules

  - Usually the answer is the xPath query of the topmost node that could be retrieved by IMPORTXML then suggest the use of other spreadsheet functions to get the required content.
  - The wiki could include the suggestion to use the W3C Markup Validation Service prior to post the question as part of the OP research effort.
- The **source file** doesn't contain the content to be parsed

  - The answer is that Google Sheets built-in functions aren't able to get that content.
  - The above could be because the content isn't included on the publically available source code of the page
  - The wiki could include recommendations to use other tools or to point users to [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerec.stackexchange.com)
- The **source file** follow the XML markup rules but the OP has problems to figure out the xPath

  - The answers could include a working xPath.
  - The wiki could include instructions about how to get one.
- The issue isn't related to the **source file**

  - The wiki could include links to questions about Google Sheets functions and formulas common errors
  - Another common question is about the the automatic refresh of the imported results

Does it makes sense to extend the [importxml](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/importxml) wiki or should it be better to proceed in a different way, like looking for/creating canonical questions? Is it too soon?

---

I was bold and jumped in into extending the [importxml] wiki. Also I created a self-answered question that could be used as reference on questions:

- [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163)

I will wait a bit for feedback about it prior to add the it's link to the [importxml] wiki.

---

NOTE: Searching for [importxml -[importxml] is:q](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=importxml%20-%5Bimportxml%5D%20is%3Aq) returns <strike>33</strike> 11 questions.

Comment: Be bold! Do it!

Comment: @ale I'm made an edit. Later I will look for importxml FAQs